# Karate - How can we see the exact request and input parameters sent when the request in feature file is called from a file

Tags: soap, reporting, karate

Karate - How can we see the exact request and input parameters sent when the request is called from a file and input parameters are coming through CSV file

In the HTML report - at the given request step,whole of the request with input parameters is displayed if the request has been put in the feature file.

```
HTML Report:
**Test 49 : Given request**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>2</intA>
      <intB>6</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

whereas, if the request had been put into an XML file and then called by using the XML in the feature file then it does not display the whole of the request in the HTML report.

For Example- Feature File:
Given request read('classpath:RequestFiles/AddRequest.xml')

HTML Report just displays the test step as: 
"Test 86 : When soap action 'http://tempuri.org/Add'"

Is anyone aware of the way to display the whole of request with input parameters if the request(in the feature file) is called from a XML file?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to attach the report or the screenshot due to restrictions at organisation level.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question at all. your best bet is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - there is also a chance you faced this bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1003

Comment: Thanks Peter. No I am not facing the bug sent by you. Its just that I am unable to see Doc String "ONLY"  for the scenarios where the request is read from a XML file .For example- Given request read('classpath:RequestFiles/AddRequest.xml') .. When the request is not read from any file then Doc String works fine. May be this is how Karate has been designed but i was just wondering that it would be really good to have Doc String  for all type of scenarios so that the exact request with input parameters is displayed in the HTML report.

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to put anything in what you refer to as the `Doc String` section of the report. Just `print` it.

```
* print someVarYouReadFromAFile
```

Also note that HTTP requests and responses will appear in the report by default, and most teams are fine with it. If you don't see this, there may be some other problem.

Finally a word of advice. I see many teams focus too much on time on making the reports "pretty". I would focus more on the question "am I able to test more scenarios and detect failures ?".

Comment: Thanks Peter! The above solution worked! This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Also, Yesterday i had showcased karate framework to all the stakeholders and the framework has been very well appreciated by everyone. Even the non technical people were able to understand it which is really great! Organisation has agreed to use this framework at enterprise level. Thank you for that !

Comment: I want to integrate Karate with Qtest ( Test Management tool) . Are you aware if anyone has done that before with karate?

Comment: @PoojaWadhwa should be possible, since people have integrated with extent and allure: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619